# connecting a receiver to computer using ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet, lan, telnet, rj-45

I learned at class that when we connect two computers with rj45 cable (I think it works for both straight and crossover cable) we can access to one of them , command line precisely, using it's IP address with telnet command in the other one , of course that has the same IP address network ( I hope that was clear enough)

Now I wanted to try this at home but not between two computers, but between my computer and my receiver ( it's called vision HD-600 from the MoreSat family and it has a firmware called nu that, I suppose, is a Linux based firmware), I really couldn't find information about how this kind of receivers works but since it works with internet and you can set an IP address to it I thought it's fine it works just like a computer.

So I set a static IP address for both devices ( 172.16.1.2/24 for the receiver and 172.16.1.1/24 for my computer) then I connected them using A STRAIGHT cable and I run ping 172.16.1.2 on my computer's cmd, and it worked, I got the response from my receiver. However telnet 172.16.1.2 didn't, it gave me an error : Error while connecting to the host - could not open a connection to host on port 23

So what should I do, first is what I'm doing even possible( I mean connecting my computer to my receiver :D ), and if it's so then what is it that I'm doing wrong ??

I'm so sorry for the long post but I wanted to explain the most I can, so you can understand the situation I'm in.

Comment: *"my receiver ( it's called vision HD-600 from the MoreSat ..."* -- There are many types of "receiver", and to use this noun without any context is poor writing.  And it turns out that such devices are more often called a "TV tuner box" or STB.  That device is more likely to host a web server than a telnet daemon, i.e. a GUI rather than a CLI. IOW try accessing the box using a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the statement "*I learned at class that when we connect two computers with rj45 cable (I think it works for both straight and crossover cable) we can access to one of them , command line precisely, using it's IP address with telnet command in the other one , of course that has the same IP address network*"  is incorrect, or at best over-simplified to the point of being meaningless, and introducing misunderstandings.   Unfortunately if you don't understand a number of key basics not apparent from your post, you won't get anywhere.

Let me start by clarifying a few things - this is still EXTREMELY simple, but at least technically correct and enough to explain the problems you have -

A typical Internet connection (as you might find in a computer or TV receiver) is built up on layers.  These layers include -

1. A physical connection - in this case Ethernet, but it could also be
    WIFI or something else.
2. A simple software system to allow computers to communicate with 
    each other over that medium.
3. A TCP/IP stack - This is what is required for the Internet to work,
    and your statement IP addresses implies you are using the TCP/IP
    protocol, which is by far the most common one.
4. The applications which then talk on TCP.

When you connect 2 computers together with an RJ45 cable, you are almost certainly meaning connect 2 computers together using an Ethernet cable and Ethernet ports (but other possibilities exist).   This meets the criteria for the first layer of connectivity in my post above, but says nothing about the intermediate layers.    If both devices are reasonably modern you can use a "straight through cable" and the devices will figure it out. Very old devices may require a cross-over cable or a switch.   You can sometimes tell if this layer is correctly connected by seeing green+yellow lights on on each side of the ethernet jack when you plug the device in (but not all devices have these)

You then jump to the IP addressing - and this it seems you have reasonably correct.

It is then that you talk about port 23.   This is another place you may have  been lead astray - the correct understanding is as follows:   IPv4 (the common Internet protocol) will allow 1 server (computer) to run many programs.   Each program is associated with at least 1 port number.  When a client (another computer) tries to talk to the server, it uses the port to communicate with the appropriate program.

**If there is no program associated with the port (in this case 23), or if there is a firewall preventing it, communication on port 23 will fail.**  This is something decided by the manufacturers of the device.

Port 23 is normally associated with "Telnet", which is among the oldest and simplest Internet protocols - typically (but not exclusively) used for entering commands and getting responses in a simple text environment.  It is also very, very insecure.   This makes it useful for controlling simple devices without requiring a web interface - but should also be very tightly controlled - if it exists at all - because of massive security risks associated with it.

It is thus probable that things are not working simply because there is no Telnet (or other) program associated with port 23 on the TV receiver - however there are a lot of other possible explanations as well (including cable faults, IP stack configuration issues, firewalls).   If this is the case, you are not doing anything wrong - **the router simply is not designed to allow you to connect to port 23.**

Comment: I just skipped that part about the TCP/IP protocol and layers I do know how all of that works it's just I didn't know I should have mentioned it

Comment: but what I didn't know is that to communicate via telnet both devices should have it, I feel really stupid :( 
I didn't notice that at class because I was running telnet just from one side unfortunately.
what we learned last year was OSI and TCP/IP models and how to configure and use routers, this year we're learning switch configuration but they talked us about ports and protocols like http and telnet and how they work and I really want to learn about protocols and ports and things related to that but I don't know from where to start 
and thanks so much by the way that was really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

So, if have understood your post correctly, your question essentially comes down to this:

- You networked your computer with your receiver through a
- You received ping response
- But Telnet is not working and you want to know why

Well, in that case, the answer is obvious: Your receiver is not running a Telnet server app. Why would it? Telnet is totally redundant to a receiver's operation. I haven't seen a single receiver that does.